# Zk: How to create a "load on demand" tree with databinding interaction?

Tags: java, mvvm, tree, zk

we would like to create a tree in MVVM pattern.

And this tree should have 2 directories passed by parameters. 
The goal is to create a directory explorer, and we would like to have a "load on demand" when a child is opened in order to have better perfomance.

For moment, we find the exemple in documentation but it is incomplete :

```
public class TreeSelectionVM {

    private TreeModel<TreeNode<String>> itemTree;
    private String pickedItem;
    //omit getter and setter for brevity
}

<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('org.zkoss.reference.developer.mvvm.collection.TreeSelectionVM')">
    <tree id="tree" model="@bind(vm.itemTree) " width="600px"
    selectedItem="@bind(vm.pickedItem)">
        <treecols>
            <treecol label="name" />
            <treecol label="index" />
        </treecols>
        <template name="model" var="node" status="s">
            <treeitem open="@bind(node.open)">
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="@bind(node.data)" />
                    <treecell label="@bind(s.index)" />
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
</window>
```

Should we manage the onOpen event ? or should we implements TreeModel and TreeNode methods (getChild & co) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more complete zk mvvm tree example which is along the lines of a directory explorer which does a load on-demand:

https://github.com/simbo1905/zktreemvvm

Just check it out with "git clone" then run it with:

```
mvn -Djetty.port=8080 package jetty:run
```

The code will start its own jetty server on a given port.

It uses [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) as an abstraction to a filesystem rather than using raw java.io.File which is harder to mock and unit test. By default the code displays a ZK screen to browse the inside of commons-vfs2-2.0.jar as though it were regular files and folders. Simply change the FILE_SYSTEM_URI uri in the ViewModel class to be file location like "file:///some/path/" to view a regular filesystem.

The zul page contains a tree and binds it's model to vm.treeModel and it's selectedItem event to the vm.pickedItem method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('org.github.simbo1905.zktreemvvm.CommonsVfs220ViewModel')">
        <tree model="@load(vm.treeModel)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.pickedItem)">
            <treecols>
                <treecol label="name" />
                <treecol label="index" />
            </treecols>
            <template name="model" var="node" status="s">
                <treeitem>
                    <treerow>
                        <treecell label="@bind(node) @converter('org.github.simbo1905.zktreemvvm.NodeConverter')" />
                        <treecell label="@bind(s.index)" />
                    </treerow>
                </treeitem>
            </template>
        </tree>
    </window>
</zk>
```

The @Converter does the friendly rendering of the FileObject data held in the tree model.

The actual ViewModel does not do much but hold the selectedItem event handler (which does nothing but log) and provides access to the TreeModel:

```
public TreeModel<FileObject> getTreeModel() {
    if (treeModel == null) {
        try {
            FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
            FileObject fo = fsManager.resolveFile( FILE_SYSTEM_URI );
            treeModel = new CachingVfsTreeModel(fo);
        } catch (FileSystemException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Could not open VFS uri: %s",FILE_SYSTEM_URI),e);
        }
        }
    return treeModel;
}
```

The main work is in the VfsTreeModel class which extends AbstractTreeModel and defines the mandatory methods

```
public class VfsTreeModel extends AbstractTreeModel<FileObject> {

// __ snip __

@Override
public FileObject getChild(FileObject parent, int index) {
    log.info(String.format("%s getChild on %s with index %s", level(parent), innerName(parent), index));
    FileObject child = null;
    try {
        FileObject[] children = parent.getChildren();
        child = children[index];
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    return child;
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(FileObject node) {
    int childCount = 0;
    try {
        FileType type = node.getType();
        if( type == FileType.FOLDER ){
            childCount = node.getChildren().length;
        }
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    log.info(String.format("%s getChildCount on %s returning %s",level(node),innerName(node), childCount));
    return childCount;
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(FileObject node) {
    boolean isLeaf = false;
    try {
        FileType type = node.getType();
        isLeaf = (type == FileType.FILE );
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    log.info(String.format("%s isLeaf on %s returning %s", level(node),innerName(node), isLeaf));
    return isLeaf;
}
```

There was a recommendation in this bug tracker to override the getPath to prevent the framework making a lot of other calls to figure out that infomation:

http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1278

That method is implemented as a walk to the root:

```
@Override
public int[] getPath(FileObject node) {
    List<Integer> paths = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        FileObject parent = node.getParent();
        while (parent != null && parent.getType().equals(FileType.FOLDER)) {
            FileObject[] children = parent.getChildren();
            for( int index = 0; index < children.length; index++){
                FileObject c = children[index];
                if( node.equals(c)){
                    paths.add(index);
                    break;
                }
            }
            node = parent;
            parent = node.getParent();
        }
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    int[] p = new int[paths.size()];
    for( int index = 0; index < paths.size(); index++){
        p[index] = paths.get(p.length - 1 - index); // reverse
    }
    log.info(String.format("%s getPath on %s",level(node),innerName(node)));
    return p;
}
```

In the following Tree Model documentation and the "Huge Data" documentation it recommends caching:

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Model/Tree_Model

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel

So in the example code the ViewModel creates a caching subclass of the VfsViewModel. Refreshing the page would create fresh objects and let the cache be garbage collected which is probably good enough for this example.

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes in order to work with 2 "root" (with a fictive root and 2 parametered directories), all is fine. Too bad, there is no explanation in documentation.

Comment: Since the documentation is a wikibook I added this example. A few minutes ago I added google guava cache after having seen a good article about that which is linked in the readme.md. The code now has a 1 minute cache per treemodel which is per viewmodel per desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation tells you to implement your own `TreeModel` and so do I ;).
Please read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel) for further information.

### Edit

Here is an example for [`TreeModel`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVC/Model/Tree%20Model) in general.
Please remember this is just a general example and you have to impl. the cache
and partial load your self.

### Reply to the first comment:

ZK's Data-Models for `MeshElement`s is independent of MVVM or MVC,
cos `model="xxx"` just calls the `setModel()` for the `Component` 
and ZK do not care about the `xxx` expression, as long as it eval's
to something ZK can find in java. And the template replaces the renderer

**An Example:**

The .zul file

```
<window title="new page title" border="normal" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('web.zk.controller.ListboxMVVM')">
        <listbox model="@load(vm.list)">
            <listhead>
                <listheader />
            </listhead>
            <template name="model">
                <listitem>
                    <listcell label="@load(each.name)" />
                </listitem>
            </template>
        </listbox>
    </window>
</zk>
```

The ListboxMVVM

```
public class ListboxMVVM {

    public UsersListModel getList() {
        return new UsersListModel(10, 0);
    }
}
```

The UsersListModel is an impl. of `AbstractListModel`

### Reply to the second comment of MychaL

And as I mentioned before, [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel) part of the ZK documentation talks about howto impl. a model for a tree.
In short,

```
public Object getElementAt(int index);
```

is called to get the expected content, where the responsibility for the logic, 
to load or unload and the way how to buffer the things you need, is yours.
The object it returns could be any you like, as you should expecting,
when reading `Object` as return type.
To generate a tree node out of your data, impl. a [renderer](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/View/Renderer/Tree_Renderer) which is more the MVC way 
but works fine with MVVM too, or write a template as above, where `each` 
is the object you'r getting from the call of `getElementAt(int index)`.

Comment: The model which is mentioned is used with MVC model...not MVVM.

Comment: Thank you, but i still not understand how to create the load on demand. I would like to have 2 directories, and each time the user open a node, load the children. For a listbox, it is easy. For moment, with a treemodel that is not. Is it the getChild method which do the load ? And in your treeModel, should we have some TreeNode<String> or directly String ? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, i will try that. i will give you a feedback soon. Anyway thank you  !

Comment: So, i created a DirectoryTreeModel which extends from AbstractTreeModel (used to load on demand). There is 3 methods to implement : getChild, getChildCount and isLeaf. I have a problem cause in order to determine a leaf, we need to call getChildCount which need to load "children" of the node. Then, the framework seems to call many times all methods...and finally all the tree is loaded ! :(

Comment: This depends on your data structure and implementation. So you may open a question on stackoverflow how to get your needed data without loading all objects.

Comment: The page you quote in this answer is implementing a ListModel not a TreeModel. The documentation you refer to is giving an example of a ListModel which loads on demand not a TreeModel. The asker of the question is quite right that there is no complete answer in the documentation. Please ensure that you actually try the code else you will be voted down.

Comment: I added a link for `TreeModel` but I am not going to edit my example cos it is thre to show that `TreeModel`/`ListModel` is MVVM as well as MVC and not how to impl. `TreeModel`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement RODTreeModel and RODTreeNode to separate the model/node side and data side so any data bean can be load on demand if the data bean implements the RODTreeNodeData interface (whilch contains two methods getChildren and getChildCount)

The basic concept/rule is let data bean to do the works, replace node.getChildren().size() with node.getChildCount(), and call dataBean.getChildCount as needed. Postpone the getChildren(), as late as possible.

Related files:

[Tree ROD classes and sample files](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/tree/master/Components/projects/Components_Practice/src/test/tree/rod)

[tree_rod_load_on_demand.zul](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/blob/master/Components/projects/Components_Practice/WebContent/tree_rod_load_on_demand.zul)

Comment: related article at my blog: http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/01/zk-tree-rod-and-load-on-demand.html